# Сохранение полученых данных из другой активити

Tags: java, android, activity, android-intent, android-shared-preferences

У меня есть 1-я активити, в которой я передаю данные в 2-ю активити и мне нужно эти данные сохранить в 2-й активити, чтобы при перезапуске программы они не исчезали.

Comment: Точно так же, как и сохранять любые другие данные. Откуда они приходят не имеет никакого значения.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте **Shared Preferences**, если вам нужно ***сохранить*** информацию. Если вам нужно ***просто передать переменные между активити***, то используйте **Intent**.

> **Shared Preferences**:

```
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

private SharedPreferences appPreferences;
private SharedPreferences.Editor appPreferencesEdit;

/*onCreate*/
protected void onCreate() {
   appPreferences = getSharedPreferences("APP_PREFERENCES", MODE_PRIVATE);
   appPreferencesEdit = appPreferences.edit();
}

/*Методы*/

/*Запись*/
appPreferencesEdit.putString("КЛЮЧ", "СТРОКА");
appPreferencesEdit.apply();//Сохранить

/*Получение данных*/
appPreferences.getString("КЛЮЧ", "ЕСЛИ ПУСТО, ИСПОЛЬЗУЕМ ЭТО.");
```

Вот [ссылка](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences) (Shared Preferences).

> **Intent**:

```
import android.content.Intent;

/*Первое активити*/
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("КЛЮЧ", "ЗНАЧЕНИЕ");
startActivity(intent);

/*Второе активити*/
Intent intent = getIntent();
String val = intent.getStringExtra("КЛЮЧ");
```

Comment: интент не сохранит значение при "перезапуске программы", как требуется в вопросе

Comment: Для этого есть Shared Preferences. Вопрос: "Сохранение полученых данных из другой активити." Можно используя Intent передать значения, а потом сохранить используя SP. Тут не один вариант, я дал методы, которые можно использовать для этой цели.

Answer (score 0):

Собственно что Вам мешает использовать оф. сайт разработчиков?

Вот основные варианты хранения информации в Android:

- Internal file storage: файловая система устройства.
- External file storage: файловая система накопителя.
- Shared preferences: подходит для хранения небольших обьемов данных по принципу ключ- значение.
- Databases: Тут я думаю все понятно. Можно для примера использовать входящую в библиотеку разработчика SQLite.(Есть также Realm, Room).

Все зависит от того какую информацию Вы собираетесь хранить.

Comment: с помощю Shared preferences все понятно когда я работаю в одной активити, но немогу понять как сделать чтобы с 1-й активити сохранять в 2-ю

Comment: @AndriyLitovskiy, для активности не имеет значения. Вам достаточно указать лишь key.

Comment: @AndriyLitovskiy, в соседнем ответе посмотрите: в метод `getSharedPreferences` первым параметром передаётся имя и по этому же имени преференс можно получить в любом компоненте приложения, не только в пределах одной активности. Или используйте [`PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager#getDefaultSharedPreferences(android.content.Context)) - это единый дефолтный преференс для всего приложения

Comment: спасибо за помощь всё ясно и понятно